# EngineIoClientDotNet not working in xamarin.forms

Tags: .net, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.forms, socket.io

I am using EngineIoClientDotNet package for send and receive string data.

I installed EngineIoClientDotNet package in PCL then implement code.

```
 public void Messages()
    {

        string result = string.Empty;

        var socket = new Socket("http://128.199.17.43:3000");
        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_OPEN, () =>
        {
            socket.Send("hi", () =>
            {
                socket.Close();
            });
        });
        socket.Open();

        //Receiving data

        var socket1 = new Socket("http://128.199.17.43:3000");
        socket1.On(Socket.EVENT_OPEN, () =>
        {
            socket1.On(Socket.EVENT_MESSAGE, (data) =>
            {
                result = (string)data;
            });
        });
        socket1.Open();
        string dd = result;
    }
```

i am following this link
https://libraries.io/nuget/EngineIoClientDotNet

but socket.Send not called.

Please guys guide me where I am wrong.

Comment: if your question involves some third party package or library, it is extremely helpful to include a link to the relevant project page

Comment: @Jason i mentioned a link, that's i am following

Comment: you are not monitoring for any Error events

Comment: @Jason i have no any error but ` socket.Send("hi", () =>
            {
                socket.Close();
            });` not fire

Comment: how do you know that you don't have any errors if you're not monitoring for them?  Maybe `Open` is throwing an exception, but you would never know about it.

Comment: @Jason but i am keeping try catch block inside messages method catch block not fire

Comment: Do the docs say that the library will raise an exception?  From my reading it appears that any error will be raised as a message.  https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232871/discussion-between-deepak-yogi-and-jason).

Comment: I have never used this library and know nothing about it.  I'm just reading the docs, which suggest that you need to monitor for error messages

Comment: @Jason  i implemented `socket.On(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, (e) =>{ var data = (string)e; });` error method inside messages method but same result, error method not fire

Comment: @Jason my error method show an error `Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error: NameResolutionFailure) `

Comment: how can resolve it

Comment: as I said before, "I have never used this library and know nothing about it".  But "NameResolutionoFailure" is a pretty explicit error message